# SQL Server Subtract certain percent

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract a certain percent of my price, into a AS columm.

```
SELECT TOP 2 *, price - (price * (discount/100)) AS discountedPrice 
FROM products 
WHERE discount != 0
```

But this seems not to work. What have I done wrong?

I want it like this, let's say price is 500 and discount is 20. Then it'll have to subtract those 20 as percent of the 500.

So 500 - 20%, just in SQL Server format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing integers : 20/100 is 0, not 0.2

Try making the division by 100.0

```
SELECT TOP 2 
*, 
price - (price * (discount/100.0)) AS discountedPrice 
FROM products 
WHERE discount != 0
```

If you want the discount price to be an int...

```
SELECT TOP 2 *, 
CONVERT(int, price - (price * (discount/100.0))) AS discountedPrice 
FROM products
WHERE discount != 0
```

Comment: That worked, but now i get those ugly six (000000) zeros. Any idea how to get rid of those?

Comment: If you want an int, do `convert(int, price - (price * (discount/100.0)))`

Answer (score 0):

**Reference** : [Link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9440)

```
SELECT TOP 2 *, price - (price * (discount/100.0)) AS discountedPrice FROM 
products WHERE discount != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that discount is an int, then you should prepend a `1.0` to cast it to a floating point number.

```
price - (price * (1.0 discount/100))
```